# Different color in some properties of this

Tags: javascript, syntax, atom-editor

[image]

Guys, why some properties have different color than others? This happens in different text editors, not just in atom. The same problem happens with SCSS.

this is very annoying. Can i disable that?

Thanks.

Comment: Editors are different but you should have a preferences option within the menu. Then find the colour scheme option and change it to minimal or none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This hapens because all js objects has some 'must have' fields lide 'id', 'language' etc. So editor parse it not like a property of your object but like a 'must have' property